# Why can't I change text of Text View of child VC from parent VC?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm working on an app that I need to change the text of text view of child view controller from a method in the parent view controller.

I have a button in child VC, when it's pressed, the view doesn't change, but a method in parent VC is called, and another method in parent VC will change the text of text view in child VC.

```
[self.delegate buttonPressed];//in child VC, call method in parent VC
```

It was working before I use storyboard.
In the parent vc, I just had code below,

```
childViewControler.textViewName.text=@"something";
```

Now I changed to storyboard, by using NSLog, I know the method to change the text is called. But no text is displayed.
I'm thinking I might add something since I am using storyboard now?
Can someone give me advice?
Thank you.

Comment: How is the parent's reference to `childViewController` populated?

Comment: Do you mean the segue?                                                - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender  {
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
}

Comment: @rickster Do you mean the segue? - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender { [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self]; }

Comment: `prepareForSegue:sender:` would be a great place to set the parent's `childViewControler` reference to the child. If you're not doing that, `childViewControler` is nil: so `childViewControler.textViewName` returns nil, and calling `setText:` on nil does nothing.

Comment: @rickster, I'm still learning while making this app. I'm not quite sure what does "set parent's childviewcontroller reference to child" mean, is that childviewcontroller alloc and init?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `childViewControler` variable in your parent view controller needs to point to the instance of your child view controller class created by the segue. If you don't assign anything to it, it's `nil`, and any messages to it do nothing.

It's unclear from the code you've posted whether it's a property, instance variable, or local variable; here's how you could do it with an instance variable:

```
@implementation ParentViewController
{
    ChildViewController *childViewController;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // if you have multiple segues, check segue.identifier
    // so you only do this for the correct segue
    childViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
}

- (void)buttonPressed
{
    childViewController.textViewName.text=@"something";
}
@end
```

The key bit is in `prepareForSegue:sender:` -- you need to make sure that the `childViewController` variable points to the view controller created by the segue.

---

It's also possible that your problem results from still having some old pre-storyboard code that `alloc`s and `init`s a child view controller and puts it into your `childViewController` variable. In that case, you'd have two instances of that view controller class around: the one created by the segue and the one you made. Only the one created by the segue is hooked into the UI, so any changes you make to the other won't be visible. You can solve this problem by getting rid of any code that creates and presents the child view controller -- the storyboard takes care of all that now, and `prepareForSegue:sender:` is the only place you need to get a reference to the child view controller.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It's working good now. I thought it could something very simple.

Comment: I have another question, after I add that line of code, the top bar with back button in child VC disappeared. How should I get it back?

Comment: That's a bit strange, and harder to diagnose without seeing more of your code and storyboard. Might be good to post as a separate question.

Comment: HI, I had it figured out. I changed the segue from push to modal yesterday, that's why the navigation bar disappear.